# How to validate with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Thanks to having to work so much, I am completely confused on JavaScript. I have tried so many things and have not gotten my form to validate even once. I have to use plain JavaScript to:

**Validate the email - the email must have @ and the domain should be yahoo.com

Phone No.: Must contain exactly 10 digits

Age: Must be a positive number less than 120

The validation should happen when the user submits the form. In case any of the above validation fails, the corresponding ﬁelds should be highlighted in red

If the validation is successful, the page should redirect to http://yahoo.com**

I'm not looking for someone to necessarily give me the exact answer, but push me in the right direction, because I do have a basic understanding of JS.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<div id="form">

<form name="myForm" action="http://fsu.edu" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" HREF="C:\Users\Neshia\Desktop\CGS3066\Form Validation Style Sheet.css" TYPE="text/css">

<script>

 function ValidatemyForm()
 {
 var email = document.myForm.email;
 var phone = document.myForm.phonenumber;
 var age = document.myForm.age;
 }

 {
 age = age.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
if(age.length != 10) 
{ 
   alert("not 10 digits");
} 
else {
  alert("yep, its 10 digits");
} 
}


 </script>


 </head>

<div id="header">

<hr id="HR1">

<h1> Web Programming: Assignment 3 </h1>

<p> Form Validation with Javascript </p>

<hr id="HR2">

</div>

 <div id="input">

First name: <br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">

<br>

Last name: <br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">

<br>

FSU Email: <br>
<input type= "text" name="email">

<br>

Phone No.: <br>
<input type="numbers" name="phonenumber">

<br>

Age: <br>
<input type="numbers" name="age">

</div>

<hr id="HR3">

<br>

<div id="Sex">

Sex: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"> Male

<br>

    <input type="radio"  name="sex" value="female"> Female

<br>

    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="other"> Other

</div>

<hr id="HR32">

<div id="languages">

Programming languages you want to learn: <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="python" value="python"> Python

<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="java" value="java"> Javascript

<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="C++" value="C++"> C++

<br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="lisp" valie="lisp"> Lisp

</div>

<hr id="HR32">

<div id="submit">

<input type="Submit" value="Submit">

</div>

<hr id="HR12">


</form>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW `<hr>` is deprecated in HTML5, don't use it, use CSS instead.

Comment: @Arjun, [no it's not, it has meaning and should *not* be replaced with CSS in cases where it's appropriate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-hr-element).

Comment: @zzzzBov OK I'm sorry. Found it somewhere on `w3schools.com`.

Comment: @Arjun, w3schools is such a bad resource that w3fools was created. Use MDN.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks!!! I will definitely use MDN later on!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be intrigued to note that html5 now validates some of these forms so you do not need to use Javascript.

See [HTML Form Validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation)

You asked about email, age and phone.

Consider the following examples::

```html
<form>
    <input type="email" name="email" pattern=".*@yahoo\.com"> <br>
    <input type="number" min="18" max="120" name="age"> <br>
    <input type="tel" name="phonenumber"> <br>
    <input type='submit'> 
</form>
```

If you want the fields to be required you could use

```html
<form>
    <input type="email" name="email" pattern=".*@yahoo\.com" required> <br>
    <input type="number" min="18" max="120" name="age" required> <br>
    <input type="tel" name="phonenumber" required> <br>
    <input type='submit'> 
</form>
```

See http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html

In your comments a few days later, you mentioned needing to do this in Javascript. I think the best way is still using HTML5 and a clever way to do this if you have to use javascript might be to set the input attributes through javascript. Something like this could get you started on the logic.

While I generally do not like getting this specific in the code, I commented things so you can get a general feel for how you can work with data in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

```js
function validate(event){
  
    // First we stop the form from even submitting until we run the code below
    event.stopPropagation();
  
    // Here we are going to place a reference to the objects we want to validate in an array
    var references = ['email','age','phonenumber'];
    
    // Now we are going to grab our list of inputs from the page
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    
    // We run through a for loop to look for specific elements
    for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      
        /*
        This line simply asks, is the 'name' of this element inside our references array. 
        This works by using the indexOf function which is built into Javascript. 
        indexOf simply provides the index where it finds the phrase you are looking for. 
        In this example, we are using it to see if an index exists by checking it against negative 1
        */
        if(references.indexOf(inputs[i].getAttribute('name')) > -1){
          
            // A switch block lets you present a different outcome based on the criteria being looked for
            switch(inputs[i].getAttribute('name')){
                
                // In this case we see if we get an email named element
                case 'email':
                
                    // We set the attributes to match our requirements for this email element and so on through this switch block for age and phonennumber
                    inputs[i].setAttribute('type','email');
                    inputs[i].setAttribute('pattern','.*@yahoo\.com');
                break;
                case 'age':
                    inputs[i].setAttribute('type','number');
                    inputs[i].setAttribute('min',18);
                    inputs[i].setAttribute('max',120);
                break;
                case 'phonenumber':
                    inputs[i].setAttribute('type','tel');
                break;
            }
          
            // When we are all done, we set the elements to be required
            inputs[i].setAttribute('required',true);
        }
    }
  
    // Now we submit the form
    event.submit();
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="age"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="phonenumber"> <br>
    <input type='submit' onclick='validate(event)'> 
</form>
```

Comment: The best JavaScript is not JavaScript ^^

Comment: I would suggest adding `pattern=".*@yahoo\.com"` to the email field, though, since that was apparently a requirement.

Comment: But if you left the fields empty, it doesn't alert anything. For that a little bit of JavaScript will be required.

Comment: Updated the inputs to have the `required` attribute for you. See http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html

Comment: This would be great but I *have* to use JS, unfortunately.

Comment: @AneshiaPrice - If this is for a school project or something I could help with JS validation but consider this one thing. What if you used javascript to set the inputs to have the attributes in my post. This would be setting the validation to use HTMLs own methods. If you have to use JS, this would be the most clever and intuitive method.

Comment: Yes its for a project, and I have another one that I don't even know where to start with. If you could help me with JS in general that would be great. I caught on so well with CSS and HTML, but JS has me lost. I would really like your help

Comment: How do I set the inputs to have the attributes? :(

Comment: @AneshiaPrice - Edited to include an idea on how you can perform this task. Good luck and happy programming

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work. Idk what I'm doing wrong, and I hate wasting your time because I need help with a lot. Ill keep tinkering around to see if I missed something, Thank you!

Comment: @Jesse thank you so much! I got it working. Now I just have to figure out how to make it require your telephone number to be 10 digits, but I am trying to figure it out myself. Thank you!

Comment: @AneshiaPrice - Please be sure to mark the answer as correct if you feel it to be so. This helps future visitors know you found the right answer. This is done by clicking the checkbox under the arrows next to my answer above.

Comment: I still cant figure out how to get the phone number to equal to 10, but itll be ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Aneshia,

You have a few problems. First the function listed in the "onsubmit" attribute of your form does not match your javascript function. Also there are some problems with your {} braces. After you get that fixed be sure to call .value after your form elements to get the value of the input ie. (document.myForm.email.**value**).

Here is the code with some fixes:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" HREF="C:\Users\Neshia\Desktop\CGS3066\Form Validation Style Sheet.css" TYPE="text/css">

<script>

 function validateForm() {
  var email = document.myForm.email.value;
  var phone = document.myForm.phonenumber.value;
  var age = document.myForm.age.value;
  console.log(age)

  var okToSubmit = true;
  age = age.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  if (age.length != 10) { 
    alert("not 10 digits");
    okToSubmit = false;
  } else {
    alert("yep, its 10 digits");
  }

  if (age > 120 || age < 0) {
    alert("Must be a positive number less than 120");
    okToSubmit = false;
  }

  return okToSubmit;
}
```

Another thing that may help is to bring up the javascript console in your browser and run your function manually in the console by typeing 'validateForm();'

Comment: Welcome to the site. Thanks for posting a nice answer with code

Comment: Hey Ive tried it but it still just redirects straight to the page without showing any message, but instead of a message, I need it to highlight red when invalid. I've even tried combining yours and Mattia :(

Comment: You can change the css class of you html elements with javascript using `document.myForm.phonenumber.className = "MyClass";` That way you could setup `MyClass` in css to style the inputs however you want when they are invalid.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type='text' id='txtEmail'/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' onclick='Javascript:checkEmail();'/>

<script language="javascript">

    function checkEmail() {

        var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
            alert('Please provide a valid email address');
            email.focus;
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Suggest checking the formatting of your post before hitting the "Post" button.

Comment: Tried this to no avail =( I even tweaked it quite a few times, but on submit it still just goes to the page instead of telling me something is wrong.